# How to regex match "{ * various * strings * }" out of many instances in a non-greedy way?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm struggling to come up with something that works here.

Environment: Notepad++ 7.8.7 (32-bit) on Windows 10 (64-bit), some testing with regex101.com

I have a game config file that contains a whole bunch of this:

```
{ apple
banana
cherry 
}
{ banana
cherry
grape
}
{ cherry
grape
apple
orange
cherry
grape
}
etc., etc.
```

I need to match individual occurrences of `{ * specific * words * }` where the `*`s DO NOT contain `{` or `}` (i.e. singular bracket blocks should be considered single matches, and no matches should contain more than one bracket block). There's no nested brackets, making things a bit simpler.

So given the example above I'd like to match something like `{ * apple * }`, or `{ * apple * cherry * }`, which would match the 1st and 3rd bracket block, but not the 2nd.

I've tried many dozens of variations on something like `(?s){.+?apple.+?}`, but they all either match nothing, have errors or timeout regex101.com (even with extended timeouts), or are too greedy, ignoring boundaries between bracket blocks.

Any insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into issues because if you want to match `{`, you have to escape it with a backslash or put it in brackets: `[{]`. Also, `.` usually doesn't match newlines unless you add a newline flag.

I think this is what you want:

```
[^{]*apple[^}]*cherry[^}]*
```

The `[^}]*` means match any character other than `}` as many times as necessary.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AaWb2L/1)

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't seem to get the right combination of flags to make Regex101 process it properly with the full config file, but Notepad++ had no problem, and it worked well. I guess I've never needed to know that curly brackets are special regex characters until now.